# OpenSSO and JasperReports Server Integration

Tags: spring-security, jasperserver, opensso

I try to integrate Jasper Server 4.7.0 and OpenSSO 11.0.

The way I chose is using OpenAM J2EE Agent and Spring Security J2EEPreAuthenticatedFilter.

When user try to access to jasper homepage, Agent redirects it to OpenAM login page, and then if authentication successful, fills user principal in HTTPServletRequest object. Spring security J2EEPreAuthencticatedFilter get principal and if it is not null, read user roles and grant access to requested resources.

The problem is after successful OpenAm authentication, J2EEPreAuthenticatedFilter return null, and user can't get access to jasperserver homepage.

Why J2EEPreAuthenticatedFilter can't get principal from HttpServletRequest object?

I use Tomcat 7 for jasper server.

This is a OpenAm agent filter and security-constraint in web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
        <display-name>Agent</display-name>
        <description>OpenAM Policy Agent Filter</description>
        <filter-class>com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ROLE_TESTER</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Authenticated</web-resource-name>
        <description></description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Then part of SpringSecurity context xml:

```
 <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
        <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
            <value>
                CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
                PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
                /xmla=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,${bean.loggingFilter},${bean.basicProcessingFilter},JIAuthenticationSynchronizer,anonymousProcessingFilter,basicAuthExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor
                /services/**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,${bean.loggingFilter},${bean.portletAuthenticationProcessingFilter},${bean.basicProcessingFilter},${bean.passwordExpirationProcessingFilter},JIAuthenticationSynchronizer,anonymousProcessingFilter,wsBasicAuthExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor
                /rest/login=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,${bean.loggingFilter},encryptionFilter,restLoginAuthenticationFilter,JIAuthenticationSynchronizer,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor
                /rest/**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,${bean.loggingFilter},${bean.portletAuthenticationProcessingFilter},${bean.basicProcessingFilter},${bean.passwordExpirationProcessingFilter},JIAuthenticationSynchronizer,anonymousProcessingFilter,wsBasicAuthExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor
                /**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,encryptionFilter,multipartRequestWrapperFilter,webAppSecurityFilter,${bean.loggingFilter},${bean.userPreferencesFilter},j2eePreAuthFilter,${bean.userPreferencesFilter},${bean.basicProcessingFilter},requestParameterAuthenticationFilter,JIAuthenticationSynchronizer,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor,switchUserProcessingFilter,iPadSupportFilter
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>


        <!--  class="org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter"  -->
        <bean id="j2eePreAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
                <property name="mappableRolesRetriever">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever">
                        <property name="webXmlInputStream">
                            <bean factory-bean="webXmlResource" factory-method="getInputStream"/>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authoritymapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
                        <property name="convertAttributeToUpperCase" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.providers.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService" />

    <bean id="webXmlResource" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource">
        <constructor-arg ref="servletContext" />
        <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean" />
```

And this id a source code of J2EEPreAuthenticatedFilter:

```
public class J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    /**
     * Return the J2EE user name.
     */
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        Object principal = httpRequest.getUserPrincipal() == null ? null : httpRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("PreAuthenticated J2EE principal: " + principal);
        }
        return principal;
    }

    /**
     * For J2EE container-based authentication there is no generic way to
     * retrieve the credentials, as such this method returns a fixed dummy
     * value.
     */
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return "N/A";
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Configuring the agent filter on its own is not sufficient for enabling declarative security for your web application. You should also set up the necessary security-constraints in web.xml.

Comment: Hi, Peter! There is security-constraint in my web.xml. I add it to my first message. User who access to jasper have ROLE_TESTER role.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, just add follow code to web.xml file:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/accessdenied.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

And delete the following code from web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JasperServerWebApp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```